# How to update from 10.04 to 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade, release-management

What is the simplest method to completely upgrade your existing 10.04 install to get the updates and packages from the 10.10 distribution? Disregarding the fact that you get the latest packages, I would like to see the package paths change to the newer version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official ubuntu.com page has information:

- For [desktop and server editions](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade).
- For [netbook edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/upgrade)

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Open the Software Sources application from the System -> Administration menu
2. Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application
3. Change the Release Update drop down to "Normal Releases" and close the application
4. Open Update Manager from the System -> Administration menu
5. Click the Check button to check for new updates.
6. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
7. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
8. Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.

Taken from:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaverickUpgrades

Comment: Why Alt-F2 for 4? Why not just start the update manager through the menu?

Comment: You first 3 steps are sufficient to allow Ubuntu to upgrade to newer versions, very well written guide.

Answer (score 7):

Go to System -> Administration -> Software Sources and change it to show all new versions, not just new LTS releases.  System -> Administration -> Update Manager.  Check for updates.  Click the button that offers to upgrade to 10.10.