# What happens with my settings, programs and files if I upgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will all my settings be kept if I update from to the next version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6539/will-all-my-settings-be-kept-if-i-update-from-to-the-next-version-of-ubuntu)

I currently use Ubuntu 11.10. When I update on version 12.04 in April 2012 what will happen to my settings, programs and so on? Will these be gone or is there a way I keep it?