# Can any body help me in upgrading my Ubuntu os to latest version 12.04 from 11.10? Have anybody faced issues?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will all my settings be kept if I update from to the next version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6539/will-all-my-settings-be-kept-if-i-update-from-to-the-next-version-of-ubuntu)

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 in my laptop. I saw ubuntu software centre showing updrade to 12.04 version. Will it retain my old files and softwares in 11.10 version or will it install a fresh copy. Have anybody faced problem while upgrading. Please inform in this post.

Answer (score 0):

It will retain your old files and software. The first time I upgraded to 12.04 my system crashed after a month due to some bad post-upgrade software updates, but it was the first time in my three years of using Ubuntu that it had happened. I re-installed 12.04 and now it's running smoothly.