# Problem when update from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: update-manager, updates, lts

I select the normal release in update manager and synaptic->update.
After i click the check button, it said that your system is up-to-date,
and I cannot get the new package of the ubuntu 10.10.

What 's the problem?

Comment: The answers to this question will help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6092/how-to-update-from-10-04-to-10-10. Untick LTS only ;)

Comment: @Takkat: I follow that answer to step 7, but no messages comes out to mention there is a new release 10.10.

Comment: Go for @maco's answer ;)

Comment: @Takkat: After key in the Alt+F2 , and run the command `update-manager -d`, the message shows up. How ever it didn't shows after checking the update manger. Maybe its a bug.

Comment: Have you run a `sudo apt-get update` lately?

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade a **long term support release** (LTS) to a newer **normal release** of the distribution we need to select *"Normal releases"* in the settings dialogue of Update Manager as shown here:

[image]