# Can't upgrade to 11.04 due to partial upgrade

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, software-center

I am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04. when I try I get this popup message from the upgrade manager:

> Not all updates can be installed
>
> Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible.

this can be caused by:

- A previous upgrade which didn't complete
- Problems with some of the installed software
- Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
- Normal changes of a pre-release version of Ubuntu

> Button: Partial upgrade or Close

When I choose the Partial Upgrade

I get an error message saying:

> can not upgrade
> An upgrade from Maverick to lucid
> is not supported with this tool

So I cant upgrade. How do I work around this, so that I upgrade?

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean laugh at him i mean laugh with him and to pay attention to it

Comment: Please add to your question the version of Ubuntu you're trying to upgrade from, it looks like you're trying to skip a version and the installer doesn't support that.

Comment: @JorgeCastro He's using 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like you are trying to upgrade from **lucid** (10.04) to **natty** (11.04). Which is not allowed.

You have to first upgrade to **maverick** (10.10) and then to **natty** (11.04).

you can however upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 (**LTS** to **LTS**) if you want to wait until precise is released in April.

Take a look at these questions and answers:

- [Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/45666/10698)
- [How do I upgrade straight from a very old release to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/a/34435/10698)
- [How to update from 10.04 to 10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6092/how-to-update-from-10-04-to-10-10)