# Can't get repository information in order to upgrade 10.10 to 11.04

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

After delaying for quite a while, I'm trying to upgrade from 10.10 through to the current version. When I hit the "check" button in Update Manager, I get the following error:

Failed to Download Repository Information. Check your internet connection.

I can't post the full list of what it failed to fetch as the website won't let me post more than 2 links, but here is the first part:

> W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security  /main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
>   , W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

etc.

> , E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

These are not packages I can disable from "other software". How can I fix this so that I can upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to upgrade from lucid (10.04) to natty (11.04). Which is not allowed.

You have to first upgrade to maverick (10.10) and then to natty (11.04).

Take a look at these questions and answers:

[Is it possible to skip releases during an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45666/is-it-possible-to-skip-releases-during-an-upgrade)
[How do I upgrade straight from a very old release to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading/34435#34435)
[How to update from 10.04 to 10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6092/how-to-update-from-10-04-to-10-10)